# How to return a value from actionPerformed to constructor

Tags: java

I am trying to display on a label (ecran) the file and path I just picked using FileDialog object.

But it is not working.
My code is returning a null value and I don't know why.

Can you please help me?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

class FerPrinc extends Frame implements ActionListener{
    Label ecran;
    public String path = null;
    public FerPrinc(String titlu){
        super(titlu);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        final Label ecran = new Label();
        add(ecran, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Button b = new Button("Choose file");
        add(b, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        b.addActionListener(this);

        System.out.println (path);
        ecran.setText(path);

        pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Choose file", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setDirectory(".");
        fd.show();

        path = fd.getDirectory()+fd.getFile();
        //System.out.println (path);
        //ecran.setText(path);
    }
}

public class TestFileDialog {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        FerPrinc f = new FerPrinc("Test Dile Dialog");
        f.show();

}
}
```

Actual result is NULL.
I am expecting to see the full path to teh file i selected.

Comment: you are printing the value of path before the button was pressed - and before that it is null indeed, the value you initialized it with.  You assign a different value only when the button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
So, I have to print the path outside of the constructor code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, this isn't how `ActionListener` or GUIs work. Swing, like most GUIs, is event driven, something happens, you react to, it's no linear.  Registering a `ActionListener` to a button isn't going to stop the code execution, waiting for the user to press the button, what happens if they never do?  Instead, you need to wait till the `ActionListener` is triggered and THEN perform the associated actions.

This is a basic concept of an observer pattern.

I think you need to speed some more time going through [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) as this is a basic concept of the API you should understand before embarking on writing your own applications

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I currently am learning and I started with AWT. Swing is the next library that i will learn. I tried to do it with AWT because my code has only a label and a button.
I did something similar with layout GridBagLayout and it worked. So I assumed that it will work also with Borderlayout... but I was wrong